# Listview scrollbar disappears

Tags: android, listview, scrollbars

I have a listview that is populated from an asynchronous task that gets data from the server.  However, when the listview first appears, the scrollbar shows up and then immediately goes away.  My main activity extends MapActivity since I display a map above the listview. Does anyone know why the scrollbar disappears and how to correct it? Below is my main layout.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 >

<TextView
    android:text="Address is: "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/address_view" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapvw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="250dp" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom layout for the listview.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

And below is the logic for creating the listview:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
 ......... some code

 List<String> viewline = new ArrayList<String>();
   ..... some code
   mapView.postInvalidate();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview, R.id.viewtext, viewline);

        ListView restaurant_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        restaurant_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        restaurant_list.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
        restaurant_list.setScrollContainer(true);
        restaurant_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " + String.valueOf(arg2) + " arg3=" + String.valueOf(arg3) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }); 

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to stop your scroll bars from fading from your `ListView`.  You only need to do one of these.

In code:

```
restaurant_list.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

In the xml:

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I added android:fadeScrollbars="false" and now they appear but they do not work.  I am testing on an emulator and if I use the mouse wheel or the pagedown key nothing happens.  Is there a way to scroll using the emulator?

Comment: Click and drag it up as you would if it were a touch screen.

Comment: I tried click and dragging and that didn't work either.  Any other suggestions?  I am unable to test on a real device right now as I am waiting to get my new Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: You can always use the up and down buttons in the emulator controls.  That should work as well.  Setting the scroll bar fading shouldn't affect scrolling at all.  Make sure you're setting scrolling enabled and not just enabled which can cause the control to be unusable.

Comment: I set restaurant_list.SetScrollingCacheEnabled(true); which didn't help either. How else do you set scrolling enabled?   I am using Google API as my target for the device.  Will that make a difference?

Comment: After you call `setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);`, call `setEnabled(true)` to make sure it's still enabled.  Also, you don't have to call `setChoiceMode` or `setScrollContainer`.  `ListView` is single choice and scrollable by default.

Comment: I finally go it to work.  The click and drag works but it seems to work in a reverse direction.  If I drag up the view scrolls down.  Whatever.  Thanks so much for your help. I don't why I couldn't find this in the books I have but I guess it better to ask the experts who have been down that road before.

Comment: Another good place to look if you ever have any Android problems is the Developer Reference at http://developer.android.com/  If you're ever having a problem with a class, you can look it up there and search through the available functions and properties to see if anything meets your needs.

Comment: I have looked at the Developer Reference.  The way I learn best is by examples.  The Developer Reference doesn't really show you how to put the pieces together.  Again, I have been programming in C for 20 years and I am like an old dog trying to learn new tricks.  But I will persevere.  I only hope I can become proficient enough to help others on StackOverflow as payback for those who have helped me.